# NullPointerException when reading file from Android external storage

Tags: java, android, storage, android-sdcard

I was having some trouble when trying to read zip file from Android external SD card.

Here is my code:

```
File[] fileArr = mVersionUpgradeViewModel.getZipFileFromSDCard();
for(int i = 0; i < fileArr.length; i++){
    System.out.println(fileArr[i]);
}

public File[] getZipFileFromSDCard() {
    File[] matchingFiles = new File[0];
    File f = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    if(f.exists()) {
        matchingFiles = f.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.endsWith("zip");
            }
        });
    }
    return matchingFiles;
}
```

And my emulator folder structure:

[image]

The zip folder is there. But with the code above, I am getting error message like:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
    at com.mainapp.asynctask.VersionUpgradeTask.doInBackground(VersionUpgradeTask.java:86)
    at com.mainapp.asynctask.VersionUpgradeTask.doInBackground(VersionUpgradeTask.java:15)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
```

The error is pointing to the first for loop. It was working last time. But after I tried the newer version installation code, the method above breaks. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `NullPointerException` usually indicates problem with variables and/or prarameters that your code works with. Effective resolution calls for debugging the code.

Comment: But then the zip file is in the sd card. Do you have any ideas why is it so?

Comment: I don't think it's duplicate. Mine is trying to read from external sd card but it returns null although the file is there

Comment: @guest176969 Have you check that "mVersionUpgradeViewModel" is not null? and what is exectly "mVersionUpgradeViewModel" this class.

Comment: `File.listFiles()` returns null under conditions which are clearly defined in the Javadoc. You aren't testing for it. Do so.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you given permission of read external storage

```
List<File> fileArr = getZipFileFromSDCard();
    for (int i = 0; i < fileArr.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(fileArr.get(i));
    }

 public List<File> getZipFileFromSDCard() {
    List<File> matchingFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    File wallpaperDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
    File[] files = wallpaperDirectory.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.getName().endsWith("pdf")) {
            matchingFiles.add(file);
        }
    }

    return matchingFiles;
}
```

Comment: Yeap in the manifest as well as runtime permission

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: yes you have set file array size is 0, please use list

Comment: Do you mind to provide me with some examples? Can you help me check the edited portion? It does not prompt the user for the permission on runtime though

Comment: show my edited ans, set file directory as you requirement

Comment: @GautamSurani Thanks for the help. I solved it already

Answer (score 0):

You initialize `matchingFiles` with an array of 0 elements:

```
File[] matchingFiles = new File[0];
```

and then you check whether `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS` exists and if so, you recreate `matchingFiles` to be an array of the files inside it ending with zip.

The stack trace clearly shows that the error is not thrown from this method, but it is safe to assume that the result of the method is problematic.

Now, `matchingFiles` is a `null` array later, so Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS exists indeed, so you either do not have reading permission of the folder, or `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS` was not set to be the Download folder in your structure shown, or the zip file you are checking is restricted from the user running the application.

You may want to check whether `matchingFiles` is `null` and if so, set it to be `new File[0]` at the end of the method to improve your code, but the solution is clearly to check your permissions to the folder and the file.

Comment: Do you mind to provide me with some examples?

Comment: @guest176969 I don't mind, but can you specify what do you need to be exemplified?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I solved it already

Comment: @guest176969 if this answer helped you solve your problem, then you may consider accepting it. If it was not helpful-enough, you might consider writing your own answer and accepting that.